# broken image in chrome and firefox works in safari

Tags: image, google-chrome, firefox, safari

I have a logo that shows up in Safari but in Chrome it appears as a broken link and simply does not show up at all in Firefox.

```
            <a href="index.html"><img src="images/logo-01.png"/></a>
```

I have re-uploaded it many times and have even tried alternative paths and file names.

anyone know how i might be screwing this up?

Comment: Have you tried making the `<image></image>` tag not self closing, and do this? Also its good practice to declare the height and width of the image so that the browser can reserve the right amount of space.

Comment: One other thought, do you have any external CSS being applied to these elements that might be the cause? I only ask because I have this same exact markup on my site and it works in Chrome, Safari, IE10 on both my PC and Mac.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this same problem.  For me, it turns out the image was corrupt.  If i  tried to open the png file up in photoshop, i would get an error saying it could not parse the file.

For whatever reason, safari could display the corrupt file, but chrome could not.  This is how i fixed my issue.  I noticed "preview" on my macbook could open the file fine.  If you are using windows, possibly try paint or gimp or some other program besides photoshop.

1. I downloaded the corrupt file onto my macbook, opened it with preview (open with > preview)
2. In the preview app, go to file > duplicate, which makes a copy of your image
3. Save that duplicated image
4. As a test, i tried opening that new copied image in photoshop and i was able to!
5. Upload new file to website.  I was able to view the image in chrome now.

Hope that helps anyone who ran into the same problem.

Comment: I'm not going to lie, this sounded like a stupid answer. Tried it because nothing else worked and it fixed it.

Comment: Apple sometimes uses a proprietary PNG format, for example in iOS applications. That will result in this behavior.
Luckily there's a tool called `pngdefry` if you need to deal with this issue in an automated way: [http://www.jongware.com/pngdefry.html](http://www.jongware.com/pngdefry.html)

Answer (score 0):

It could be an issue with your file structure.  Right now your links are using relative paths (e.g. `href="index.html"`).  This is fine if the file you're referencing is in the same directory as the current page file.  But if your current page is located elsewhere, like in a 'pages' directory or something, then you need to tell the links to start from the site root.  That would look like `href="/index.html"` (note the slash).  So for the image, you'd have:

`<a href="/index.html"><img src="/images/logo-01.png"/></a>`

Comment: You don't need that unless you're doing `../image/logo-01.png` The leading `/` is not needed.

Comment: Assuming the page is within the same directory as the images, you can leave it off. i'll update the answer to be more specific

Comment: It would help if he gave more code and his directory structure.  I'm assuming it is the same directory though considering it works in Safari.

Comment: yeah the site works on every page in safari, what should i provide to be more helpful? im sorry i have only been doing this for a few months and am still learning.