# Displaying as broken Image in Chrome and Firefox - ServletOutputStream

Tags: java

I am trying to retrieve an image from back-end and display it in a browser window. It is working fine in Internet Explorer but it is displaying as a broken image in chrome and forefox.

```
docImage = dpcInfo.getUploadedDocImage();

response.setContentType("image/png");
response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"GTM.png\"");
response.setContentLength(docImage.length);

try {
        ServletOutputStream sos = response.getOutputStream();
        sos.write(docImage);
        sos.flush();
        sos.close();
}
```

Here `docImage` is a byte array which contains the retrieved image.

How can I display it in all the browsers?

Comment: If you put the URL of the image in the browser address bar and it works then you need to look at your code. If it still displays a broken image icon then you need to look at the image file.

Comment: There is no URL for the image. It is being retrieved from backend apps.

Comment: OK, if you put the image on the webserver, just for testing, is it broken in some browsers?

Comment: I am not clear with your question. Could you please reframe it?

Comment: The first thing to check is if it is the image which is broken or your code. IE may be more forgiving of a malformed image file than other browsers. If you serve the image directly from the web server to the browser with none of your code then you can see where to direct your effort: if your code is not broken then there is no point trying to fix it.

Comment: I totally agree with your point. But how can i pull the image without any code as it comes from back end application and not from database.

Comment: Adding to my query, i am trying to display the image in the new browser using window.open in javascript. Can someone help me please

Comment: Check in browser you have abblocker on browser

Answer (score 0):

I know, this question was asked a while ago, but for all with similiar problems, try this one:

> I ran into this same problem. For me, it turns out the image was corrupt. If i tried to open the png file up in photoshop, i would get
>   an error saying it could not parse the file.
>
> For whatever reason, safari could display the corrupt file, but chrome
>   could not. This is how i fixed my issue. I noticed "preview" on my
>   macbook could open the file fine. If you are using windows, possibly
>   try paint or gimp or some other program besides photoshop.
>
> I downloaded the corrupt file onto my macbook, opened it with preview
>   (open with > preview) In the preview app, go to file > duplicate,
>   which makes a copy of your image Save that duplicated image As a test,
>   i tried opening that new copied image in photoshop and i was able to!
>   Upload new file to website. I was able to view the image in chrome
>   now. Hope that helps anyone who ran into the same problem.

Source: [broken image in chrome and firefox works in safari](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14901720/broken-image-in-chrome-and-firefox-works-in-safari/27816914#27816914)